# Find out which button was clicked and run code accordingly in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to build a calendar in access form. I have 42 buttons (D1, D2,.....D42) in the form. I want to find out which button was clicked to get the date. I dont want to use each of the 42 btn's event procedure to run this. I have tried the following method which does literally nothing...

```
Private Sub form_Click()

    Dim findbtnname As String
    
    If Me.ActiveControl.ControlType <> acCommandButton Then
        Exit Sub
    Else: findbtnname = Mid(Me.ActiveControl.Name, 2, 1)
    End If
    
    Select Case findbtnname
        Case 1 To 6
            PrevMonDates '
        Case 7 To 31
            CurrentDates
        Case 32 To 42
            NextMonDates
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Here PrevMonDates, CurrentDates and NextMonDates are some custom functions to get the dates. The mid function is used to get the button no. I just need to find out which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a public function like the following:

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION D_Click(BtnID AS INTEGER)
    SELECT CASE BtnID
        CASE 1 TO 6
            PrevMonDates
        CASE 7 TO 31
            CurrentDates
        CASE ELSE
            NextMonDates
    END SELECT
END FUNCTION
```

Then for each button, set the on_click property to: `=D_Click(n)`, where n is the name of the button.
For simplicity, this can be done with VBA:

```
DIM BTN AS CONTROL
DIM i AS INTEGER
FOR i = 1 TO 42
    SET BTN = CONTROLS("D" + TRIM(i))
    BTN.ONCLICK = "=D_Click('" + TRIM(i) + "')"
NEXT
```

Comment: You didn't mention where should I put the last portion of your code!!!

Comment: @NashidIftekhar, in any desired event (mostly form_load). Or better, open the form in design mode using VBA (in a module or other form) and just run it once. A slight modification is required to use the form name.

Comment: I used that code in form_load but now it shows an error message after clicking the buttons: "The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Object Required."

Comment: I had some problems with my functions that's why its showing the error. Now It works fine. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnClick` property to make that happen.When loading the form, use the `Onload` event to bind the buttons `OnClick` property to an `ActionFunction`.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If c.Name Like "Date Button *" Then
            c.OnClick = "=ClickAction(""" & c.Name & """)"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Private Function ClickAtion(ByVal ObjName As String)
    MsgBox ObjName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for using `WithEvents`.

See a very similar example of mine having a demo for download: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme) and the full explanation in my article:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html?preview=yawJg2wkMzc%3D)

Main code:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Helper class for form Palette for event handling of textboxes.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private WithEvents ClassTextBox As Access.TextBox


Public Sub Initialize(ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox)

    Set ClassTextBox = TextBox
   
    ClassTextBox.OnClick = EventProcedure
   
End Sub


Public Sub Terminate()

    Set ClassTextBox = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    ' Select full content.
    ClassTextBox.SelStart = 0
    ClassTextBox.SelLength = Len(ClassTextBox.Value)
    ' Display the clicked value.
    ClassTextBox.Parent!CopyClicked.Value = ClassTextBox.Value
    ' Copy the clicked value to the clipboard.
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

```vb
Option Explicit

' Form to display the Windows Phone 7.5/8.0 colour theme.
' Also works as a basic example of implementing WithEvents for a form.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private ControlCollection   As Collection


Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Load events for all colour value textboxes.
   
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
    Dim Control         As Access.Control
   
    Set ControlCollection = New Collection
   
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            Set EventProcedure = New ClassTextboxSelect
            EventProcedure.Initialize Control
            ControlCollection.Add EventProcedure, Control.Name
        End If
    Next
   
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set Control = Nothing
   
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Unload events for all colour value textboxes.
   
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
   
    For Each EventProcedure In ControlCollection
        EventProcedure.Terminate
    Next
   
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set ControlCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class module, *clsBtnEvents*

```
Public WithEvents BtnGrp As Access.CommandButton

Private Sub BtnGrp_Click()
    Dim BtnNum As Integer
    BtnNum = Val(Mid(BtnGrp.Name, 2))

    Select Case BtnNum
        Case 1 To 6
            Call PrevMonDates(BtnNum)
        Case 7 To 31
            Call CurrentDates(BtnNum)
        Case Else
            Call NextMonDates(BtnNum)
    End Select
End Sub
```

In the Form's code window,

```
Dim MyButtons As New Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim btn As clsBtnEvents

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is CommandButton Then
            Set btn = New clsBtnEvents
            Set btn.BtnGrp = ctl
            MyButtons.Add btn
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

This way, every time a button is clocked, the *BtnGrp_Click()* kicks in, you can then use this in your custom functions to identify which button was clicked. Hope this is kind of workaround.

Comment: I tried different ways to make this work but it didn't work. I put the custom functions (PrevMonDates etc) in the same class module (now come to think about it should I put these in other module?). Btw, those functions don't have any (btnnum) properties. I am puzzled right now.

Comment: Umm, it depends on how you wanted to use the _custom fn_. If these functions are specific to calendar form then you probably should keep them in the same module (i.e. clsBtnEvents). However, if these _fn_ are more **general** use and can be used in other parts of your database, it would be better to move them to a separate module - you need to test it though.